# Plugins and Hacks Active Directory Integration Authentication failed

Tags: wordpress, plugins, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to configure the WordPress Active Directory Integration Plugin.
but every time when I am testing, it fails with following error:

```
INFO]   method authenticate() called<br/>
[INFO]   ------------------------------------------<br/>
         PHP version: 5.3.5<br/>
         WP  version: 4.2.3<br/>
         ADI version: 1.1.7<br/>
         OS Info    : Linux ikonikmedia.com 2.6.32-042stab093.5 #1 SMP Wed <br/>Sep 10 17:39:49 MSK 2014 x86_64<br/>
         Web Server : cgi-fcgi<br/>
         adLDAP ver.: 3.3.2 EXTENDED (201302271401)<br/>
         ------------------------------------------<br/>
[INFO]   LDAP paging: not available<br/>
[NOTICE] username: archana<br/>
[NOTICE] password: **not shown**<br/>
[INFO]   Options for adLDAP connection:<br/>
         - account_suffix: @nblenergy.com<br/>
         - base_dn: dc=nblenergy,dc=com<br/>
         - domain_controllers: meetings.nblenergy.com<br/>
         - ad_port: 10636<br/>
         - use_tls: 0<br/>
         - network timeout: 6<br/>
[INFO]   Checking domain controller ports:<br/>
[INFO]   - meetings.nblenergy.com:10636 - OK<br/>
[NOTICE] adLDAP object created.<br/>
[INFO]   max_login_attempts: 1000<br/>
[INFO]   users failed logins: 0<br/>
[NOTICE] trying account suffix "@nblenergy.com"<br/>
[ERROR]  Authentication failed<br/>
[WARN]   storing failed login for user "archana"<br/>
```

Website URL:

> http://nobleenergytownhall.com/

Please suggest if better plugin is available for LDAP or active directory

Answer (score 0):

It feels like advertising but it might help you. I've written the [authLdap plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/authldap/) to authenticate against any LDAP. Perhaps that one might help you. Main development takes place on [github](https://github.com/heiglandreas/authldap) so for issues or configuration-questions please use the issue tracker there.

Comment: I am using the authLdap plugin but Nothing change.

Comment: Something will have changed, as I think the messages must be different. Perhaps you can add more details to the question as to what configuration values you are providing and what log-messages output.